# AutoMapper not mapping IEnumerable Issues

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to use Automapper to map one enumerable to another but keep getting the following console error :

```
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Flg.Producer.Snowflake.V2.Proxies.Snowflake.Book>'
to
'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Flg.Producer.Snowflake.V2.Proxies.Snowflake.Book>>'
```

Code block :

```
public Task<IEnumerable<Book>> GetAllBooks()
{
    Task<IEnumerable<BookResult>> result;
            
    using (IDbConnection snowflakeDbConnection = _dbConnection)
    {
        result = snowflakeDbConnection.QueryAsync<BookResult>(string.Format(SelectBooks));    
    }
    var books = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Book>>(result);

    return books;
}

public class Book: IRequest
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class BookResult : IRequest
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<IEnumerable<SnowflakeDb.BookResult>, IEnumerable<Book>>();
    }
}
```

Any help or right guidance will be apreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please read the error message.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the AutoMapper issue as there is a mismatch from `IEnumerable` to `Task<IEnumerable>`.

Please make changes for the following code block:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Book>> GetAllBooks()
    {
       Task<IEnumerable<BookResult>> result;
            
       using (IDbConnection snowflakeDbConnection = _dbConnection)
       {
          result = await snowflakeDbConnection.QueryAsync<BookResult>(string.Format(SelectBooks));    
       }
       var books = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Book>>(result.ToList());

       return books;
    }
```

Also, there is no need to have IEnumerable in AutoMapper `CreateMap()`. The following code block will just work fine for IEnumerable.

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<SnowflakeDb.BookResult, Book>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not awaiting your dapper QueryAsync

await that line that QueryAsync then make sure your mapping is good and in start-up DI container.
Add services.AddAutomapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

Also, your CreateMap method in the Profile constructor don't need that IEnumerable, change to this =>

CreateMap<MappFromEntity, MappToEntity>();
Replace MappFromEntity and MappToEntity as accordingly.

And you'll be just fine.